Cloudflare --force build for React
00:11:49.557    
00:11:49.558    Using v2 root directory strategy
00:11:49.653    Success: Finished cloning repository files
00:11:51.302    Checking for configuration in a wrangler.toml configuration file (BETA)
00:11:51.302    
00:11:51.425    No wrangler.toml file found. Continuing.
00:11:51.583    Detected the following tools from environment: npm@9.6.7, nodejs@18.17.1
00:11:51.664    Installing project dependencies: npm clean-install --progress=false
00:11:53.563    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
00:11:53.767    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
00:11:53.767    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.768    npm ERR! While resolving: react-bubble-ui@1.1.2
00:11:53.768    npm ERR! Found: react@18.3.1
00:11:53.769    npm ERR! node_modules/react
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!   react@"^18.3.1" from the root project
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!   peer react@">=18" from @nextui-org/accordion@2.0.38
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!   node_modules/@nextui-org/accordion
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!     @nextui-org/accordion@"2.0.38" from @nextui-org/react@2.4.6
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!     node_modules/@nextui-org/react
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!       @nextui-org/react@"^2.4.6" from the root project
00:11:53.769    npm ERR!   293 more (@react-aria/utils, @react-types/shared, ...)
00:11:53.769    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.769    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
00:11:53.769    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-bubble-ui@1.1.2
00:11:53.770    npm ERR! node_modules/react-bubble-ui
00:11:53.770    npm ERR!   react-bubble-ui@"^1.1.2" from the root project
00:11:53.770    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.770    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! node_modules/react
00:11:53.772    npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0" from react-bubble-ui@1.1.2
00:11:53.772    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-bubble-ui
00:11:53.772    npm ERR!     react-bubble-ui@"^1.1.2" from the root project
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! 
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! For a full report see:
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-09-04T07_11_52_421Z-eresolve-report.txt
00:11:53.772    
00:11:53.772    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2024-09-04T07_11_52_421Z-debug-0.log
00:11:53.787    Error: Exit with error code: 1
00:11:53.788        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/snapshot/dist/run-build.js)
00:11:53.788        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:652:26)
00:11:53.788        at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:537:28)
00:11:53.788        at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
00:11:53.799    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
00:11:54.656    Failed: error occurred while running build command

When I get this message, how can I fix it? Or can I deploy the build file? It builds normally on my mac but I don't know how i can use --force for Cloudflare Page!
NO envirnoment variables
Build command:
npm run build
Build output directory:
/build
Root directory:
/
Build comments on pull requests:
Enabled

I tried to change it to npm run build --force but it doesn't change anything.

Add more details what are your build configuration and environment variables that will help to find the exact issue.

please add this value in env variables and than try to build don't change npm run build command.
NODE_VERSION:16.13.1

youu sir are theeeeeeeeeee god!

I am adding answer please vote up. Thanks

please add this value in env variables and than try to build don't change npm run build command.
NODE_VERSION:16.13.1
